# jgroups auth and encrypt

Tags: infinispan, jgroups

I have gone through http://jgroups.org/manual/index.html#Misc which says that encrypt node should be configured as below (1):

```
    <ENCRYPT encrypt_entire_message="false"
         sym_init="128" sym_algorithm="AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding"
         asym_init="512" asym_algorithm="RSA"/>
```

However, below that there is another section called "using a keystore" which says encrypt block should be as below (2):

```
<ENCRYPT key_store_name="defaultStore.keystore"
     store_password="changeit"
     alias="myKey"/>
```

When I try (1), messages are not encrypted. If I want to use (2), is encrypt_entire_message property valid?

I have tried to find a simple end-to-end example for encrypt with no luck. Can someone point me to a working example or share their working jgroups config.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The JGroups testsuite has some encrypt tests which might be able to help, see [here](https://github.com/belaban/JGroups/tree/master/tests/junit-functional/org/jgroups/protocols)